# Zend Quickstart Tutorial Conceptual Problem

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

I am trying to learn zend framework, and managed to get through the whole quickstart tutorial they have. However, there is something that I simply can not understand, and was hoping somebody can help me with.

In the tutorial, you create a db-table class, a mapper, and a model. I read the documentation, and understand the purpose of the db-table class (define table, relations, create/fetch rows). When you query the db-table class, you'll get an object of class db-table-row, which you can use to manipulate a specific record in the db.

However, I can not understand why the tutorial would have me create a mapper and a model, nor the reason for defining getter/setter methods in the model (shouldn't those be provided by db-table-row?)

Even in the controller, they created an object from the model class and the mapper class, then they completely ignored the model object, and just used the mapper object.

Is there any need at all to have those 3 classes? what different purpose does each fulfill? As far as I can see, all I need is the db-table class, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When you query the db-table class, you'll get an object of class
>   db-table-row

No you get db-table-rowset instead which is collection of row . 
secondly

you don't even need db-table class

```
$dbTable = new Zend_Db_Table('tableName');
```

But since db-table class allow you to define relationship between other tables inside it (business logic) hence became important .

db-table-row became important when the entity is important for e.g User Table . Inside your custom db-table-row for user you can add method `getTopics();` which return rowset for all the topics created by theat user hence fruther helping with business logic.

Comment: excellent, but what about the mapper and the plain model they use in the quickstart tutorial? are they required? do they serve a purpose?

Comment: If database table is source of data then use mapper(DbTable) . If data is coming from any other source for example websrervice (reading twitter timeline) then use plain model . If family of db tables define your entity then define that entity as plain model which uses those db tables through composition .